# ASP.Net Core API always returns 401 but Bearer token is included

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP .NET Core web api and I generate a JWT token for authorization purposes but whenever I make a request with Postman with Bearer token header I get 401 Unauthorized. Same when I try from my front-end that's consuming the API. When I remove Authorize everything works fine

Tried changing Authorize in my header to

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
```

Also visited [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to ensure the JWT Token is valid which it is.

**Function that generates JWT Token**

```
public User AuthenticateAdmin(string username, string password) 
{
    var user = _context.User
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username 
            && x.Password == password);

    //return null if user is not found 
    if (user == null) return null;

    //authentication successful so generate jwt token
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor 
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] 
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role)
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        SigningCredentials = 
            new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    user.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    
    user.Password = null;
    return user;
}
```

---

**Startup :**

```
public class Startup 
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) 
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration 
    {
        get;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
    {
        services.Configure<AuthMessengerOptions>(Configuration);
        
        var connection = @"Host=localhost;Database=PayArenaMock;Username=postgres;Password=tim";
       
        services.AddDbContext<PayArenaMockContext>(
           options => options.UseNpgsql(connection));
        
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        // services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
        // {
        //     auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        //             .AddAuthenticationSchemes(
        //                 JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        //       .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
        // });
        
        services.AddCors();
        
        // Note - this is on the IMvcBuilder, not the service collection
        // services.AddMvcCore()
        //     .AddAuthorization() 
        //     .AddJsonFormatters(options => options.ContractResolver = 
        //         new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
        
        // services.AddMvcCore()
        //     .AddJsonFormatters(options => 
        //         options.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
                
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(
                    CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        
        //configure strongly typed settings objects
        var appSettingsSection = 
            Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
        
        //configure JWT authentication
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
        
        services.AddAuthentication(x => 
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = 
                JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = 
                JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x => 
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters 
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

        services.AddScoped<IUserService,UserService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) 
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) 
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        } 
        else 
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        
        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
            
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
    
}
```

---

**Controller :**

```
//[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BusinessListingsController: ControllerBase 
{
    private readonly PayArenaMockContext _context;

    public BusinessListingsController(PayArenaMockContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/BusinessListings
    [HttpGet]
    //[AllowAnonymous]
    //[Authorize(Roles = Role.Admin)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<BusinessListing>>> 
        GetBusinessListing() 
    {

        //var businesslisting = _context.BusinessListing
        //    .Include(b => b.CategoryNameNav);
      
        var businesslisting = await _context
            .BusinessListing
            .ToListAsync();
            
        return Ok(businesslisting);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you maybe have [Authorize] on the top of the controller which contains token generation method?

Comment: Do you set 

> [Authorization]

 header like "Bearer *your token*"?

Comment: @Jamil I did in react, do the same in Postman and it does not work

Comment: Check if you chose the correct method(GET or POST), url, other headers and body. In postman it's the same, you choose Authorization header and type "Bearer " + your token, and don't forget to check the checkbox.

Comment: Did you add `app.UseAuthorization();` to your startup?

Answer (score 49):

I had same issue, but after moveup

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

to before line of

```
app.UseAuthorization();
```

in

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ..
    app.UseAuthentication();
    ..
    app.UseAuthorization();
    ...
}
```

it worked.

Comment: This was exactly my issue!

Comment: Thank you for this response it fixed my problem too!

Comment: Or in my case, pay attention and don't put app.UseAuthorization twice. lol Thanks for drawing my attention to my goof!

Answer (score 22):

I had this issue with dotnet core 3.1, and I was flipping every switch trying to get this to work. Eventually what ended up getting this to run was tletle's answer. Execute `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UseAuthorization()`. To elaborate on tletle's answer, below is the relevant code.

In `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication(); // this one first
    app.UseAuthorization(); 
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

My authentication middleware is in an extension method I wrote that is called from the `ConfigureServices()` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
        public static void ConfigureAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            string issuer = configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Issuer");
            string signingKey = configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Key");
            byte[] signingKeyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingKey);

            services.AddAuthentication(opt=>
            {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options=>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = issuer,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = issuer,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ClockSkew = System.TimeSpan.Zero,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(signingKeyBytes)
                };
            });
        }
```

and the token was generated using this extension method:

```
public static string GenerateApiUserToken(this ApiUser user, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    string signingKey = configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Key");
    string issuer = configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Issuer");
    int hours = configuration.GetValue<int>("Jwt:HoursValid");
    System.DateTime expireDateTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(hours);

    byte[] signingKeyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingKey);
    SymmetricSecurityKey secKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(signingKeyBytes);
    SigningCredentials creds = new SigningCredentials(secKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var authClaims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.RoleName)
    };

    JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer:issuer,
        audience: issuer,
        claims: authClaims,
        expires: System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(hours),
        signingCredentials:creds
    );
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    string writtenToken = handler.WriteToken(token);

    return writtenToken;
}
```

My Controller class:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Produces("application/json")]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("/[controller]/values", Name="MyController")]
public class MyController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
```

If the `[Authorize]` tag is on the controller, you should remove any that are on member methods; I left one on the method I was testing and the fix wouldn't work until I removed it.

Comment: Argh...spent like a day and a half and when I did your fix it worked.  I sometimes feel like I spend more time figuring out stupid issues like this than actual programming.

Comment: I share your pain, it was about the same for me haha. Great to hear I'm helping other devs - thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Once I had the same problem after I switched from HTTP to HTTPS.  It was working fine in POSTMAN with HTTP but when I switched to HTTPS it began to return **401 unauthorized**

The problem was solved as soon as I added

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

inside

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
    }
```

within the

```
public class Startup
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with this issue for hours, and trying different things from the multiple questions. Here is how I identified the problem:

Turn on the logging for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` package in your appsettings.json file

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Trace",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
// other attributes
}
```

This will log the authentication failures to the Visual Studio server console.

[image]

In my case, I was not passing the `expires` parameter to the `new JwtSecurityToken` constructor while generating the token. But I was validating the token lifetime in the `TokenValidationParameters` constructor.

Hope this helps to figure out the solutions if you have tried everything else.

Answer (score 2):

It works finally, not a 100% sure why but I did `headers: { Authorization: "Bearer" + " " + Bearer }` in my react app. I do the equivalent in Postman and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and this was what i did on postman, in the header section using bulk edit.

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImRhbmllbEBtZ2ljLmNvbToxMTExMTE6IiwibmJmIjoxNTcwNjIxMDE5LCJleHAiOjE1NzMyOTk0MTksImlhdCI6MTU3MDYyMTAxOX0.cTjhhHqf75VN0RwQvly6nppeNUkKbzQ5_ZVPFyruuKPBQ
```

Also remember to include the authentication filter at the top of your endpoints, which is [Authorize] in your case.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a bearer token then add the below decorated

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

instead of only `[Authorize]`