# Is there a mandatory order of statements in the Configure method of a ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Preface:**

I spent the whole afternoon trying to understand why my application was always returning a *401 unauthorized* response to my requests.

After much much digging, hair pulling and swearing, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185834/asp-net-core-api-always-returns-401-unauthorized-whenever-i-send-a-request-with), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59622327/4628597):

> putting `app.UseAuthentication();` before of `app.UseAuthorization();` solves the problem.

In my case I saw that I was still receiving some CORS errors (that were not happening if I removed the `[Authorize]` attribute) so I moved `app.UseCors(AllowSpecificOriginsPolicy);` first and everything worked!

The working order is:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseCors(AllowSpecificOriginsPolicy); // this one first
    app.UseAuthentication(); // this one second
    app.UseAuthorization(); // this one third
    ...
}
```

**Question:**

My question is, how do we know what is the right order here?
Is it written somewhere in the documentation or you just find it with trial and error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information was recently added to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order), in the form of an example `Configure` implementation:

> ```
> public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
> {
>     if (env.IsDevelopment())
>     {
>         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
>         app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
>         app.UseHsts();
>     }
>
>     app.UseHttpsRedirection();
>     app.UseStaticFiles();
>     // app.UseCookiePolicy();
>
>     app.UseRouting();
>     // app.UseRequestLocalization();
>     // app.UseCors();
>
>     app.UseAuthentication();
>     app.UseAuthorization();
>     // app.UseSession();
>
>     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
>     {
>         endpoints.MapRazorPages();
>         endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
>             name: "default",
>             pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
>     });
> }
> ```

Note that:

> Middleware that is not added when creating a new web app with [individual users accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is commented out.