# .NET CORE 5, VUE 2x, Docker, JWT returns always 401

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, jwt, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-5.0

I need the help of this community to solve a very tedious problem.
I am deploying an app that uses .net core 5 web api as backend, vue2x as a frontend.
The backend is conneted to mongodb and everyhthing is orchestrated by docker-compose.
I have JWT authentication and CORS in place.

Problem is that when I run docker-compose up on my local machine (windows), everything works.

When I run docker-compose up on my server (ubuntu), I cannot authenticate and I always get a 401 (even with postman).

Yes I have read this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#order
and this
[ASP.NET core JWT authentication always throwing 401 unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61976960/asp-net-core-jwt-authentication-always-throwing-401-unauthorized)
and this
[ASP.Net Core API always returns 401 unauthorized whenever I send a request with Bearer token included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185834/asp-net-core-api-always-returns-401-unauthorized-whenever-i-send-a-request-with).

What is very annoying is that docker should free us from the "it works on my machine" kind of problems, so I really don't know where to bash my head anymore.

Here it comes some code

Startup

```
  public class Startup
{
    readonly string LocalHostpecificOrigins = "_localhostSpecificOrigin";
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        #region db-config
        // requires using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
        services.Configure<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>(
    Configuration.GetSection(nameof(BookstoreDatabaseSettings)));

        services.AddSingleton<IBookstoreDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
            sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

        services.AddSingleton<BookService>();


        // requires using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
        services.Configure<MisteryBoxDataBaseSettings>(
    Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MisteryBoxDataBaseSettings)));

        services.AddSingleton<IMisteryBoxDataBaseSettings>(sp =>
            sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MisteryBoxDataBaseSettings>>().Value);

        services.AddSingleton<MisteryBoxService>();


        services.Configure<UserDatabaseSettings>(
           Configuration.GetSection(nameof(UserDatabaseSettings)));

        services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
            sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<UserDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

        services.AddSingleton<UserService>();
        #endregion

        services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(name: LocalHostpecificOrigins,
                                      builder =>
                                      {
                                          builder.WithOrigins(
                                                "http://localhost:8081", "http://localhost:8080",
                                                "https://localhost:5001", "http://localhost:5000",
                                                "http://188.166.121.146:8081", "https://188.166.121.146:8081")
                                          .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST")
                                          .AllowAnyHeader()
                                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                                          .AllowCredentials();
                                      });
                });
        services.AddControllers();


        services.AddAuthentication(
            x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(token =>
            {
                token.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                token.SaveToken = true;
                token.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("JwtKey").ToString())),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Kool_Backend", Version = "v1" });
        });

    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Kool_Backend v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(LocalHostpecificOrigins);
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

UserController.cs

```
 [EnableCors("_localhostSpecificOrigin")]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserService _userService;
    public UserController(UserService service)
    {
        _userService = service;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<User>> Get() =>
       _userService.Get();

    [HttpGet("{id:length(24)}", Name = "GetUser")]
    public ActionResult<User> Get(string id)
    {
        var user = _userService.Get(id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return user;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<User> Create(User user)
    {
        _userService.Create(user);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", new { id = user.Id.ToString() }, user);
    }


    [HttpPut(Name = "UpdateUser")]
    public IActionResult Update([FromBody] User userIn)
    {
        var user = _userService.Get(userIn.Id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _userService.Update(user.Id, userIn);

        return NoContent();
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("authenticate")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login([FromBody] User user)
    {
        var token = _userService.Auhtenticate(user.Email, user.Password);

        if (token == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
        return Ok(new { token, user });
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./Kool-Backend/Kool-Backend.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "Kool-Backend.csproj"
COPY ./Kool-Backend .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "Kool-Backend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Kool-Backend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Kool-Backend.dll"]
```

Docker-compose

```
      version: "3.4"

  services:
    mongodb:
      container_name: mongodb
      image: mongo
      volumes:
        - ~/mongo/data:/data/db
      ports:
        - "27017:27017"
    koolbackend:
      image: moscaen/koolbackend
      restart: unless-stopped
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Kool-Backend/Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "5001:443"
        - "5000:80"
      environment:
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
        - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001
        - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=verysecretpassword
        - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/Kool-Backend.pfx
      volumes:
        - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
      depends_on:
        - mongodb
```

I omitted the frontend part because, I have problems contacting the backend api with postman.
Again it works when the docker-compose up is runned from my local machine (i.e. https://localhost:5001), but not on the server (i.e. https://1xx.1xx.1xx.1xx:5001)

If someone has some ideas, please let me know.

Thanks and have a great day!

PS: here are some screenshots

[errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvPzd.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvPzd.png shows ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. So the root problem is an SSL failure — an SSL cert problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I tryed a more relaxed cors policy and it looks like it's working.

I have replaced

```
  services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: LocalHostpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.WithOrigins(
                                            "http://localhost:8081", "http://localhost:8080",
                                            "https://localhost:5001", "http://localhost:5000",
                                            "http://188.166.121.146:8081", "https://188.166.121.146:8081")
                                      .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST")
                                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                                      .AllowCredentials();
                                  });
            });
```

with

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); });
        });
```

and I have moved it below the

```
services.AddSwaggerGen() ...
```

finally I have setup CORS in the Configure method as

```
...
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
...
```

This allowed me to remove the attribute from the controller.

```
...
[EnableCors("_localhostSpecificOrigin")]
...
```

In short I still don't know what fixed the issue, but this setup now is working.

Thanks all for your attention and have a great day!