# Dotnet core Token Based Authentification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have been struggling for few days now trying to fix unauthorized access error when passing JWT token from MVC application to WEB Api.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations I found that that the problem was due to that my requests were being sent as Http instead of https. After changing my request to use https, problem was resolved.

[ASP.Net Core API always returns 401 but Bearer token is included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185834/asp-net-core-api-always-returns-401-but-bearer-token-is-included)